# How to use to .join() to convert letters to string

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have created two list of tuples, a list of every possible 3-letter combination, and a list of every possible 4-digit combination. I now need to combine every tuple-element to create a string, and I tried using the -join() function but it doesn't work for some reason. I have used these different codes, but i only get an empty list as a result.

```
l = combinations('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ', 3) #List of every 3-letter combination
d = combinations('0123456789', 4)                    #List of every 4-digit combination
print(list(l))
print(list(d))

joinl = [''.join(t) for t in l]
print(list(joinl))
```

Which gives med the output:

```
[('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'E'), ('A', 'B', 'F'), ('A', 'B', 'G') ... ('V', 'X', 'Z')] 
[('0', '1', '2', '3'), ('0', '1', '2', '4'), ('0', '1', '2', '5'), ('0', '1', '2', '6') ... ('6', '7', '8', '9')] 
[]
```

Now i've tried coding the joining of the tuples these two different ways,

```
joinl = [''.join(t) for t in l]
print(list(joinl))
```

and

```
joinl = []
for t in l:
    joinl.append(''.join(t))
print(list(joinl))
```

but I only get an empty list as a result. Instead of

```
[(ABC), (ABD) ... (VXZ)] 
[(1234, (1235) ... (6789)]
```

Comment: Combinations are generators and are consumed once they are iterated. Turn them into lists.

Comment: Remove `print(list(l))` and `print(list(d))`. You are already consuming the output.

Comment: Not every routine/function/method/operator/keyword has a tag. Please choose tags from a list & read their wikis. Tag [tag:join] is for the relational DB operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from itertools import combinations

L = list(combinations('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ', 3)) #List of every 3-letter combination
d = list(combinations('0123456789', 4))                    #List of every 4-digit combination
print(L)
print(d)

joinl = [''.join(t) for t in L]
print(joinl)
```

Using `l` (lower-case L) as a variable name must be avoided (PEP8) as it can be very similar to `1` (one) and `I` (upper-case i) in some fonts.

Comment: I still only get an empty list when i try to print  : print(joinl)

Comment: @AmalieMampendaLerøyJobarteh this code snippet definetely works, can you verify that you are using `list(combinations(...))` and not just `combiantions(...)`?

Comment: I had written 
l = combinations('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ', 3) instead of
l = list(combinations('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ', 3)) It worked now! Thank you!

Comment: @AmalieMampendaLerøyJobarteh can you mark the answer with a tick if it solved your question? Helps sort out already answered questions and is a nice way to thank tthe author.